# In FlashDevelop, how do you make it stop automatically qualifying types with their packages' names?

Tags: flashdevelop

Let's say you make a class called "Entity" in package com.something1.something2.  Now let's say you type out the following code in package com.something1.something3:

```
var e:Entity = new Entity();
```

Except that FlashDevelop comes in and turns it into this:

```
var e:Entity = new com.something1.something2.Entity();
```

How can you make it stop doing that?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This behavior usually happens in 2 cases:

- you import 2 classes with the same name but from different packages (ex: com.foo.Entity, bar.baz.Entity),
- your code contains a local or instance declaration which hides the class' root package (ie. var com:SomeType hides 'com' from com.foo.Entity).

Comment: Is there not a way to make it stop doing that, at least when it's not a result of the first condition?